# asp:UpdatePanel work only when other inputs are valid

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have this `UpdatePanel`:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="CheckManager" runat="server" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="checkUsername" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="canUse" runat="server" Text=""/>
  <asp:Button ID="check" runat="server" Text="Usable?" onclick="check_Click" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="check" eventname="Click" />
  </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

update code:

```
 protected void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (HotelEntities h = new HotelEntities())
        {
            UserHandle u = new UserHandle();
            if (u.FindUserByUsername(h, username.Text.ToString()).Any())
            {
                canUse.ForeColor = Color.Magenta;
                canUse.Text = "You cannot use this username";
                username.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                canUse.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                canUse.Text = "you can use this username";
            }
        }
    }
```

but works only when other inputs in form (that have validations e.g. `RequiredFieldValidator`) are valid  .

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain _"works only when"_? I have no idea what _works_ or _works not_ means.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "not works" means that don't update the label

Comment: You haven't shown code which updates the label(which label).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **CausesValidation="false"** for the button for which you do not want validation to be  performed when the Button control is clicked.

```
<asp:Button ID="check" CausesValidation="false"  runat="server" 
 Text="Usable?" onclick="check_Click" />
```

[Button.CausesValidation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx): Gets or sets a value indicating whether validation is performed when the Button control is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ValidationGroup property same with the button and your textbox validations etc. For example you have required field validator near the textBox1. And you have two buttons. If you dont use ValidationGroup, you wont be able to click any of them without validating your inputs. 
You may
[Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup.asp) to see an example